# Can I turn any Javascript function into an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm seeing functions on node.js being turned into objects after being exported (to another javascript file), but these objects aren't being assigned any sort of properties, they're just being used to emit events. So my question is, would it be valid to turn ANY function into an object?

Comment: Do you meen something like `new Car()`, where `Car` is a function? Because that's a common thing in Javascript to create an instance of a `class` (which is basically a function).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. How do I know then if it's a class vs a function, or are they one and the same? Basically can I turn any function into a new object?

Comment: Nearly everything in JavaScript is an object and yes functions are also objects. So you're just creating a instance of an invoked function which is also an object. Just read something like this: https://blog.simpleblend.net/is-everything-in-javascript-an-object/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every function in javascript actually *is* an object. I'm not sure about the process you are referring to where a function is *turned into* an object - but I can tell you that it already is one.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function for more information.

Answer (score 2):

A JavaScript function is an Object. It's just that simple.

EDIT:

Based on your comment: a common naming convention is to name functions with a capital letter if they are intended to be instantiated. Typically, yes, you can create an object instance using any function. At least one exception to that are lambda functions.